# iPhone OpenGL ES Texture2D Masking

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, masking

What's the best choice when trying to mask a texture
like ColorSplash or other apps like iSteam, etc?

I started learning OPENGL ES like... 4 days ago (I'm a total
rookie) and tried the following approach:

1) I created a colored texture2D, a grayscale version of the first
texture and a third texture2D called mask

2) I also created a texture2D for the brush... which is grayscale and
it's opaque (brush = black = 0,0,0,1 and surroundings = white =
1,1,1,1). My intention was to create an antialiased brush with smooth
edges but i'm fine with a normal one right now

3) I searched for masking techniques on the internet and found this
tutorial ZeusCMD - Design and Development Tutorials : OpenGL ES Programming Tutorials - Masking
about masking. The tutorial tells me to use blending to achieve
masking... first draw colored, then mask with
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO) and then grayscale with
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE) ... and this gives me something close to
what i want... but not exactly what i want. The result is masked but
it's somehow overbright-ed

4) For drawing to the mask texture i used an extra frame buffer object (FBO)

I'm not really happy with the resulting image (overbright-ed picture)
nor with the speed achieved with this method. I think the normal way
was to draw directly to the grayscale (overlay) texture2D affecting
only it's alpha channel in the places where the brush hits. Is there a
fast way to achieve this? I have searched a lot and never got an
answer that's clear and understandable. Then, in the main draw loop I
could only draw the colored texture and then blend the grayscale ontop
with glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).

I just want to learn to use OPENGL ES and it's driving me nuts because i can't get it to work properly. An advice, a link to a tutorial would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For something that will actually work on the iPhone, try [texture combiners](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Combiners).

I used them to mask an RGBA texture against another, transformed alpha texture.
This was for generating a complicated shadow in the absence of a stencil buffer,
but your situation doesn't seem so different.

Note that this link explains combiners in terms of fragment shaders, which works well.
Unfortunately the combiners are more complicated than their shader counterparts.